# How do i remove a fixed parameter in url path

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on an application which has several entry points like

```
const LOGIN_ENTRY = "login";
const DOCS_ENTRY = "docs";
const APP_ENTRY = "app";
```

this makes the `app` run like this

```
http://localhost:3000/app/home
http://localhost:3000/app/videos/tutorial
```

I want to remove `app` from the url path.

When I initialize `APP_ENTRY = ""`,
this `http://localhost:3000/home`does not work, unless i include another `/` like this `http://localhost:3000//home`

How do I strip the extra `/` so that the `app` goes away completely in the entire url path.

Note: `const APP_ENTRY = "something-else"`; returns `http://localhost:3000/something-else/home`

```
const getPaths = (config: BasicConfig, parentPath: string = ""): Paths =>
  config.reduce((paths, configItem) => {
    const currentPath = `${parentPath}/${configItem.name}`;
    return {
      ...paths,
      ...(configItem.container ? { [configItem.container]: currentPath } : {}),
      ...{ [currentPath]: currentPath },
      ...(configItem.name === LOGIN_ENTRY ? { LOGIN_ENTRY: currentPath } : {}),
      ...(configItem.name === APP_ENTRY ? { APP_ENTRY: currentPath } : {}),
      ...(configItem.children ? getPaths(configItem.children, currentPath) : {})
    };
  }, {} as Paths);
```

the config function is

```
const config: BasicConfig = [
  { name: LOGIN_ENTRY, container: containerKeys.LOGIN },
  {
    name: APP_ENTRY,
    container: containerKeys.LAYOUT,
    role: "user",
    isPrivate: true,
    children: [
      { name: "home", role: "user", container: containerKeys.HOME },]}]
```

I create the url path by calling `getPaths(config)`

Comment: can you please post your code example ?

Comment: @inkredusk I have added the code that get the path and the config function

Comment: How are you using these path prefixes to construct URLs? What is `parentPath`?

Comment: @Phil, i just call `getPaths(config)`